# Re-evaluate all formulas dependencies in the workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to re-evaluate all formulas (dependencies and all) in a large workbook.

I cannot use my usual keyboard shortcut for this: Ctrl-Alt-Shift-F9 (1) because I'm working remotely and it seems the keyboard isn't registering this particular key-chording.

Is it possible to re-evaluate all cells formulas, along with their dependencies, using items on the menus or setting a particular option?

Thanks.

(1): https://superuser.com/questions/448376/what-is-the-excel-hotkey-to-re-calculate-all-formula-in-sheet

Answer (score -1):

Dont think there is this option on the menu

the only way is to add a module with the following code into the personal.xlsb (for example)

```
Sub Workbook_Tree_Rebuild_and_Forced_Recalculation()
    ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation
End Sub
```

and then add a button on the menu to run this macro

Comment: -1 @Steve: thats is not the equivalent of Ctrl-Alt-Shift_F9. The VBA equivalent is Application.CalculateFullRebuild

Comment: not according to Ms Documentation > http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: The MSDN documentation you reference is incorrect. The ForeceFullCalculation property makes Excel calculate all formulas at each recalculation, but does not rebuild the dependency tree.